# Random bytes generation with C# for use as an AES encryption key

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have to generate a 128 bits key for AES in C#.

Since I am not familiar with C# could someone please show me a simple code on how to generate 16 random bytes?

Comment: Your question title is asking for C code, but your question sounds like you're asking for C#. Please clarify the result you are looking for.

Comment: C# is just a language, but crypto-quality secure random numbers are a function of the platform. The answers below are specific to .NET. If you are *not* on .NET then speak up.

Comment: To solve your [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for X: set `aes.KeySize` to `128`, call `aes.GenerateKey()`, read `aes.Key` which now has a new random key in it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you use [`Random.NextBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill an array of bytes with random values.

**However, your case is special.** Since you are using the random values for encryption, you need to generate a cryptographically secure sequence, meaning that an attacker who gets a part of the sequence that you generated cannot reliably predict any part of the sequence that follows.

Here is how you do it:

```
var rnd = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
var b = new byte[16];
rnd.GetNonZeroBytes(b);
```

Comment: "RNGCryptoServiceProvider is obsolete. To generate a random number, use one of the RandomNumberGenerator static methods instead."

Answer (score 2):

To generate a cryptographically secure random number, such as one that's suitable for creating a random password, use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class or derive a class from System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.

See [RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you're using the .Net Framwork...

```
/* This will store your bytes in a byte array 0 - 15 (16 values) */      
    Random random = new Random();
    byte[] values = new Byte[15];
    for(i=0; i<15; i++){
      values[i] = Convert.ToByte(random.Next(0, 127)); // max for a byte
    }
```

To help you with further C# hurdles try checking out the following Resources:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home (Social form)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361664(v=vs.110).aspx (Everything .Net)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/ (Getting started with .net)

Note: if you want these bytes to represent actual ASCII characters, change the range of the rand to `random.Next(33,126);

Update: RNGCryptoServiceProvider is definitely better for your use case.